# Did the Shunammite woman expect Elisha to resurrect her son in 2 Kings 4:23?

Tags: 2-kings

2 Kings 4:

> 18And the child grew, and one day he went out to his father, who was with the harvesters.
>
> 19“My head! My head!” he complained to his father.
>
> So his father told a servant, “Carry him to his mother.”
>
> 20After the servant had picked him up and carried him to his mother, the boy sat on her lap until noon, and then he died. 21And she went up and laid him on the bed of the man of God. Then she shut the door and went out.
>
> 22And the woman called her husband and said, “Please send me one of the servants and one of the donkeys, that I may go quickly to the man of God and return.”
>
> 23“Why would you go to him today?” he replied. “It is not a New Moon or a Sabbath.”
>
> “**Everything is all right**,” she said.

From faith's perspective, did the Shunammite woman expect Elisha to resurrect her son? Did she have faith in Elisha? in Elisha's God?

Comment: Faith [in-whom] : Elisha אֱלִישָׁ֖ע or יְהֹוָה֙ HaShem?

Comment: Good point. I added.

Answer (score 2):

Initially the Shunammite woman did not believe Elisha when he told her she would have a son.  She said to Elisha,

> No, my lord.  Don’t mislead your servant, O man of God! (2 Kings 4:16)

Yet, one year later, she gave birth to a son.  When the child later died, sitting on her lap, she laid him on the bed in the room designated for Elisha.  Then she told her husband that she had to go to Elisha quickly, even though it was neither a New Moon nor the Sabbath.  When Elisha’s servant Gehazi met her and asked if she, her husband and her son were all right, she replied,

> Everything is all right (2 Kings4:26)

Grief does strange things to people.  In her distress, she was unable to speak of the cause of her anguish, yet Elisha discerned it at once.

> Leave her alone! She is in bitter distress, but the LORD has hidden it from me and has not told me why (2 Kings 4:27).

Her grief in the loss of her one, her only son, became clear when she cried out to Elisha,

> Did I ask you for a son, my lord?” she said.  “Didn’t I tell you, ‘Don’t raise my hopes’?” (2 Kings 4:28)

> The woman could not understand why the Lord would take from her that which she had been given as a special demonstration of his grace and the trustworthiness of his word. (NIV Study Bible notes)

After Elisha raised the dead boy back to life, she fell at his feet and bowed to the ground.  My NIV Study Bible notes make this comment:

> The woman gratefully acknowledged the special favour granted to her by the Lord through Elisha, and silently reaffirmed the verbal confession of the widow of Zarephath (1 Kings 17:24).

The Shunammite woman was God-fearing and a believer.  Why, she even went to the trouble of preparing a room for Elisha so he could be a guest and eat and sleep whenever he passed that way.  Her distress at the loss of her son motivated her to turn to Elisha for help.  When she said “Everything is all right,” it was more likely done in order to prevent anyone else from sharing her distress.  She did not even tell her husband that the boy had died, nor did she confide in Elisha’s servant.  Instead, she made haste to seek out the prophet, Elisha.  Only then did she unburden her grief and insist that Elisha himself return with her to her home (2 Kings 4:30).

Her faith was displayed by her insistence on having Elisha personally return with her to the room where her dead son lay.  She most certainly had faith in Elisha, whom she acknowledged as “a holy man of God” (2 Kings 4:9) and in the God whose grace resulted in the birth of a much loved son.

Answer (score 1):

#### Did the Shunammite woman expect Elisha to resurrect her son in 2 Kings 4:23?

An August 1, 2010, *Watchtower* article entitled [**Draw Close to God “Lift Up Your Son”**](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010571#h=6) brings up some interesting points:

> Without delay and with her husband’s consent, she makes the trip of some 20 miles [30 km] to Mount Carmel to see Elisha. Upon meeting him, she does not give way to wailing or weeping or other ways of expressing acute sorrow. Is it because she has heard that Elijah, Elisha’s predecessor, had restored life to the son of a widow? (1 Kings 17:17-23) Does the Shunammite have faith that Elisha could do the same for her young son? Whatever the case, she refuses to leave for home until Elisha agrees to go with her.

Additional points that could show how the Shunammite woman had shown faith in Jehovah God:

- The Shunammite woman knew that Elisha was "a holy man of God". (vs. 9)
- Elisha prophesied that she would have a son and she received that son. (vs 16, 17)
- There may have already been a pattern of spirituality since both she and her husband were aware of requirements for "a new moon or a sabbath." (vs. 23)
- When asked about the welfare of her family, including the child, she says "All is well." (vs. 26)

While the Biblical account does not specifically state that she had faith in God, her actions show that she did.

Answer (score 1):

The Shunamite woman is extremely perplexed and does not know what to do except that Elisha might hold the key.

The phrase translated "Everything is all right" in the OP is highly interpretive - it is literally שָׁלֽוֹם = shaloam = "peace".  Note the helpful comments below:

Cambridge commentary:

> **It shall be well** The Heb. word is literally ‘Peace’. But it is used in salutations and enquiries after the welfare of another, as
> below in verse 26. Here however the woman appears to use it as a means
> of putting aside further questioning. So it would be equivalent to
> ‘Let be’. ‘Say no more’. ‘Let me have my way’.

Ellicott:

> **It shall be well**.—Omit it shall be. The expression may be equivalent to our common “all right;” admitting the truth of what is
> said, yet persisting in one’s purpose. She did not want to be delayed,
> nor to have her faith shaken by argument.

Barnes:

> **It shall be well** - Rather, as in the margin, "Peace." i. e., "Be quiet
>
> - trouble me not with inquiries - only let me do as I wish."

Pulpit:

> And she said, It shall be well. She uttered the single word shalom,
> literally, "peace," but used, like the German gut, or the English "all
> right," to content an inquirer without giving him a definite answer.

Thus, the Shunamite appears to say: "OK - but get out of my way. I am going to the prophet"

Answer (score 0):

The Shunammite woman is a believer.

> 2 Kings 8:1 Now Elisha had said to the woman whose son he had restored to life, “Arise, you and your household; go and live as a foreigner wherever you can. For the LORD has decreed a seven-year famine, and it has already come to the land.”
> 2So the woman had proceeded to do as the man of God had instructed. And she and her household lived as foreigners for seven years in the land of the Philistines.

She believes right away, with no hesitation. She believes in the LORD and Elisha his prophet. By faith, she has left her home for 7 years.